# PHP 5.4 new object -> call method

Tags: php, object, methods

I thought in php 5.4 this was possible

```
(new object())->method();
```

But I am having trouble when both the object and methods are stored in a classes variables I have tried the following,

```
new $this->object($this->params)->$this->method();
new ($this->object($this->params))->$this->method();
new $this->object($this->params)->{$this->method}();
```

I can't seem to get it working unless I am mistaken and it cannot be done. Thank you

Comment: That is some terrible code right there that is

Comment: I understand it is hard to understand but this code isn't being used in production.

Comment: It doesn't matter, because it probably will be in the future

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on this test (http://codepad.viper-7.com/mcPvpG) (updated test), it ought to work if you wrap the `new object()` in its own `()`, and wrap the method name in `{}`.  Because it is the expression `new object()` which returns the object, rather than just the call to the constructor `object()`, that expression needs to be wrapped as `()`.

This is super-convoluted though. If you have the opportunity to rethink this, I would do so.

```
public $object = 'ClassName';
public $method = 'method';

// Called as:
(new $this->object($this->params))->{$this->method}();
```

Here's an example using `ArrayIterator::valid()`:

```
class instantiator {
    public $object = "ArrayIterator";
    public $method = "valid";
    public $params = array(1,2,3);

    public function do_it() {
        var_dump((new $this->object($this->params))->{$this->method}());
    }
}

$i = new instantiator();
$i->do_it();
// Prints bool(true)
```

Comment: Yes I understand this, I am just mucking about that's all, learning through trial and error, thanks.

Comment: @ShaShads Check the updated example. It should actually work out, as crazy as it would be in production.